# Widget doesn't show in WP panel

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating my first plugin for WP. I've widget which I would like show in my sidebar show I decided to make widget. I made this but it doesn't show anything in my WP panel.

```
    <?php

//Klasa widgetu
class Skpp_Widget extends WP_Widget {
    //Konstruktor
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(
            'skpp_widget',
            'Widget SKPP',
            array( 'description' => 'Wyświetla jeden produkt' )
        );
    }

    //Główna funkcja widgetu
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        echo 'test';
    }
}


//Rejetrujemy widget
function skpp_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'skpp_widget' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'skpp_load_widget' );
```

Answer (score 0):

function custom_widgets_init() {

register_sidebar( array(

```
    'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'custom' ),

    'id' => 'sidebar-1',

    'description' => __( 'Appears on posts and pages except the optional Front Page template, which has its own widgets', 'custom' ),

    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',

    'after_widget' => '</aside>',

    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',

    'after_title' => '</h3>',

) );
```

}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'custom_widgets_init' );